# NOSQL Database, Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, database, jquery-mobile, nosql, web-crawler

I have started a mobile application build in jquery mobile, somewhat similar to the Amazon app. I have done some research on what type of database Amazon uses to store data and I have found that they use a NOSQL database. For my project I will be needing to continuasly crawl web data, in which will be a massive amount of data that I need to sort, store and call on upon end-user request. My questions are as follows:

1.Should I use a NOSQL database? 
2.what kind of NOSQL database should I use? 
3.How secure is a NOSQL database? 
4.Are there third party NOSQL databases that I could use that are already structured for my need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Depends on your data model. If you using objects then perhaps they fit nicely in a document based model such as Mongo DB.
2) Depends on many things, do you want to use replication sets? Sharding? Do you want to use geographical based querying.
3) Very secure, depending on how you secure it.
4) There are many types of NoSQL Databases which all benefit different requirements and different types of data modelling. You can, and many companies do, use hybrids of DB technologies. There's no set answer, well there is, but it would need to come from the person that knows the data the best.